# Examine the convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

For $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, let $a_1=\alpha$ and $a_{n+1}=2-\dfrac{2}{a_n^2+1}$. Examine the convergence of the sequence ${\{a_n\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for different values of $\alpha$. Also find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ whenever it exists.

Let's first look at the difference $$a_{n+1}-a_n=2-\dfrac{2}{a_n^2+1}-a_n\\=\dfrac{2a_n^2+2-2-a_n^3-a_n}{a_n^2+1}=\dfrac{-a_n(a_n-1)^2}{a_n^2+1}$$ How do I determine the sign of this? Also $a_1=\alpha$ is a parameter, so how do I determine the sign of $a_2-a_1$?
If we have shown that the sequence converges, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=l,$ right?

Can we then write $l=2-\dfrac{2}{l^2+1}$ and why? Which gives $l=0$ or $l=1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $0$ is stable. But what happens when you start with $1+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon > 0$ small?

Comment: First note that $a_{n+1}>0.$ Therefore $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}<0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: It is not hard to see that $a_1=1$ and $a_1=0$ give a stable solutions. If other starting values approach $1$ or $0$ they will also approach those stable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We make the following observations:

1. If the limit $a_n\to l$ exists, then it must be $l=0$ or $1$ as you claimed.
2. To determine the sign, let $f(x)=2-\frac2{x^2+1}$ then $f(x)\in[0,2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. This means no matter what $\alpha$ is, we always have $a_n\in[0,2)$ for all $n\geq2$, so let's forget $a_1$ and focus on $a_2$.
3. Then by your steps, we have $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{-a_n(a_n-1)^2}{a_n^2+1}\leq0$ for all $n\geq2$, which shows the sequence is non-increasing.

Since $a_n\geq0$ and the limit is $0$ or $1$, we need to discuss $2$ cases:

- If $a_2<1$: Since $a_n$ is non-decreasing (by observation 3) and bounded below by $0$, it must converge to $0$ by observation 1.
- If $a_2\geq1$: Note that $f(x)\geq1$ for all $x\geq1$, hence $a_2\geq1$ implies $a_n\geq1$ for all $n\geq2$, this means $a_n$ is bounded below by $1$ and non-increasing, thus it must converge to $1$.

Now all you need is to find out which $\alpha$ leads to $a_2<1$ and $a_2\geq1$.